If a linear combination of a discrete gaussian is another one then how LWE samples are indistinguishable from Uniform?
I was reading "Improved Discrete Gaussian and Subgaussian Analysis
for Lattice Cryptography" by Nicholas Genise, Daniele Micciancio, Chris Peikert and Michael Walter. In section 1.2 it states that linear combination of discrete gaussian is another discrete gaussian with some properties. With that in mind, the decisional LWE problem is based on distinguishing a tuple $(a, b = a\cdot s + e)$, both $a, b$ from uniform. Suppose we use the secret distribution and error distribution to be equal to a discrete gaussian. Then, can we conclude that a discrete gaussian is indistinguishable from a uniform?
That is very counter-intuitive, since a uniform vector can contain much more values on the tail of the distribution. If that is the case, then we can actually use any small error from any distribution as long as we keep the secret distribution a discrete gaussian and the reduction can be based on the theorems proposed in the paper. Do we have a margin (For example discrete Uniform($-\sigma$, $\sigma$) is indistinguishable from discrete Gaussian(0, $\sigma$)) to make a uniform indistinguishable from a discrete gaussian in a convolution or is it an open problem?
Does that change in other LWE setups (RLWE and MLWE)?

Note that $\langle \vec a, \vec s\rangle + e$ is not a discrete Gaussian, but the reduction of a discrete Gaussian modulo $q$.
For high-enough width discrete Gaussians, their reduction modulo $q$ is statistically indistinguishable from uniform.
This should be easier to understand intuitively, but note that the above motivates an important concept in lattice-based cryptography, namely the lattice smoothing parameter.
This quantifies precisely how high the width of a discrete Gaussian must be for the reduction modulo $q$ (or modulo a lattice, more generally) of the discrete Gaussian to be statistically close to uniform.
You can read about this in many places, but see Lemma 4.1 of Micciancio Regev 2004 for the precise result I'm talking about.
